# decomposition into the sum of rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis

could any one give me a hint for this one? please not the whole solution
Let $f$ be a non constant rational function and $z_1,\dots, z_n$ be its poles in $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$. we have to show that $f$ can be written as $f=f_1+\dots,f_p$ where each $f_j$ is a rational function.

Comment: and is there supposed to be some relation between $p$ and $n$, and between the $f_j$ and the $z_i$?

Comment: I would guess that each $f_j$ is supposed to have only one pole.  In that case the magic phrase is either "partial fractions" or "principal parts".

Answer (score 1):

Under Robert Israel's interpretation, you can do induction on the number of poles. Expand $f$ in Laurent series in $\{z:0<|z-z_n|<r\}$ for sufficiently small $r$. The series has finitely many negative powers; puts them into $f_n$. Apply the inductive hypotheses to $f-f_n$ and conclude.